# How to convert bool vector to char vector?

Tags: c++, vector

for example, we have a vector  test with 1 0 content. I would like to convert this to char vector with the same content.

thanks

Comment: Please take the time to read this: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . It is easier for use to help when we are able to understand the problem.

Comment: Take a shot at implementing this yourself and come back if you run into problems you cannot solve.

Comment: Different isn't the same. `bool` has two values: `true` and `false`. `char` has at least 256 values. What do you want the values to be?

Comment: Do you want to print (or display) the content of the bool array?  You may not need character conversion for this.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for vector of chars where true is '1' and false is '0' you can simply create new char vector the size of your bool vector and iterate through filling it with corresponding to bool char:

```
std::vector<bool> bools{ 1,1,1,0,1,0 };
std::vector<char> chars(bools.size());

for (size_t i = 0; i < chars.size(); ++i)
    chars[i] = bools[i] ? '1' : '0';
```

Comment: You could also use `'T'` and `'F'` instead of `'1'` and `'0'`.

Comment: This isn't idiomatic, and comparing an `int` to a `std::vector::size_type` isn't that wise, at the very least, it will emit an annoying warning. Plus, you should explain your answer

Answer (score 2):

You can use `std::transform` and a back inserter to do that.
As a minimal, working example:

```
#include<algorithm>
#include<iterator>
#include<vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<bool> bools{ 1,1,1,0,1,0 };
    std::vector<char> chars;

    std::transform(
        bools.cbegin(), bools.cend(),
        std::back_inserter(chars),
        [](auto b) { return b ? '1' : '0'; });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Two solutions:
1.
This is not a separate solution, just a variant of Killzone Kid's one in C++11 dialect, where range-for is more idiomatic.

```
std::vector<char> to_vchar(const std::vector<bool> in, char f = '0', char t = '1')
{
    std::vector<char> ret;
    ret.reserve(in.size());
    for (auto&& b : in)
        ret.push_back(b ? t : f);
}
```

2.
I'll abuse here that you haven't specified what values you wanted for true and false, so I'll use 0 and 1 (instead of '0' and '1'). Feel free to add '0' to each element if you want to move it, as numbers are guaranteed to be continuous in any charset in C++.

```
std::vector<bool> vbool = { 0, 1, 0, 1 };
std::vector<char> vchar(vbool.begin(), vbool.end());
```

I'd choose the second as it's the more idiomatic of these.